# Is "them" in this sentence a sense subject or object of the to-infinitive "to last" in terms of their meaning?

Tags: infinitives

I would like to ask you a question relating to-infinitive.

Here is the sentence.
"Although we build things to last, we don't expect them to last indefinitely."

I wonder whether "things" right before "to last" is a subject(in terms of its meaning) or a object(in terms of its meaning) of "to last".

Any explanations would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Things* in the first clause acts as both the object of the finite verb *build* and the subject of the infinitive *to last*. The sentence may be paraphrased

> We build things in such a way that the things will last.

*Them* in the second clause is a little trickier. It is again the subject of the infinitive *to last*; but it is not the object of *expect*. That object is the entire clause *them to last indefinitely*; the sentence may be paraphrased

> We don't expect that they will last indefinitely.

However, when this is cast as an infinitive clause rather than a *that* clause ('content clause'), its subject occupies the "object position" in the main clause, and English syntax requires it to take object case: *them*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no question of meaning I think, "things" in the first subclause (starting with "Although") is *an object* of the verb "build".  The "to last" is an infinitive used as an adverb, "how do we build things?" - "we build things *to last*".  That use of the infinitive is similar to "we care to impress", "we play to win".